# Limit Processing of Async MSMQ Message

Tags: msmq

I'm receiving messages from MSMQ in async fashion. How can I limit processing of messages upto **n** messages and then reenable the event to start processing again? (I don't want to limit the thread numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this with MSMQ. You will either have to implement this behavior in your sending application or receiving application.